# como obtener un registro de una tabla SQL server con Python

Tags: python-3.x

Cordial saludo.
Actualmente estoy consultando una tabla en SQL Server por medio de Python.
Este es el código.

```
from ConexionSqlServer import conexion

try:
    with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
        consulta = "SELECT * FROM GpsInventario WHERE tipo_plan='AVANZADO' AND plataforma='FLOTASNET' \
        AND fecha_desactivacion='1900-01-01' ORDER BY equipo;"
        # Podemos llamar muchas veces a .execute con datos distintos
        cursor.execute(consulta)
        #Con fetchall traemos todas las filas
        dispositivos= cursor.fetchall()
        # Recorrer e imprimir. Recorrer es necesario para tener los datos disponbles
        for gps in dispositivos:
            #este es el campo a mostrar
            print(gps)
        print(gps[0])
except Exception as e:
    print("Ocurrió un error al consultar con where: ", e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conexion.close()
```

cuando lo ejecuto, me devuelve algo así:

```
('vd-116', 5051)
('vd-217', 6051)
('vd-218', 5425)
vd-218
```

yo deseo obtener el dato 'vd-116' pero intento colocando print(gps[0]) ya que pensé que este era su índice, pero me sorprende ya que el dato que me entrega es vd-218.
Pensé que de pronto debía colocar otro índice así: print(gps[0][0]), pero esto lo que hace es tomar la letra v del dato vd-218.

Agradezco su ayuda para entender que debo hacer para poder obtener el dato vd-116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar `cursor.fetchall()` te va a entregar todas las filas de tu consulta en la forma de una lista de tuplas, cada tupla será una fila, por lo que una forma de ver la salida sería así:

```
for fila in dispositivos:
    for columna in fila:
        print(columna)
```

Si quieres solo mostrar una columna determinada por índice, bien puedes hacer algo así:

```
for fila in dispositivos:
    print(fila[0]) # Primer columna de cada fila
```

En tu ejemplo, tienes un problema de identación y `print(gps[0])` está fuera del ciclo, por lo que te imprimiría el valor de la primer columna de la última fila leída.